# Pandas sample with weights

Tags: pandas, sample

I have `df` and I'd like to make some sampling from it with respect to distribution of some variable. Let's say `df['type'].value_counts(normalize=True)` returns:

```
A 0.3
B 0.5
C 0.2
```

I'd like to make something like `sampledf = df.sample(weights=df['type'].value_counts(normalize=True))` such that `sampledf ['type'].value_counts(normalize=True)` will return almost the same distridution. How to pass dict with frequency here?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`Weights` has to take a [series of the same length](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html) as the original df, so best is to add it as a column:

```
df['freq'] = df.groupby('type')['type'].transform('count')
sampledf = df.sample(weights = df.freq)
```

Or without adding the column:

```
sampledf = df.sample(weights = df.groupby('type')['type'].transform('count'))
```

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the answer above, it should be noted that if you want to sample each type equally you should adjust your code to:

```
df['freq'] = 1./df.groupby('type')['type'].transform('count')
sampledf = df.sample(weights = df.freq)
```

In the case of two classes. If you have more than two classes, you can use the following code to generalize the weights calculation:

```
w_j=n_samples / (n_classes * n_samples_j)
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to create "a series of the same length as the original df". Instead you can just sample from each group by passing the factored output of `value_counts` like this:

```
col = 'type'
sample_factor = .3
# sample size per group
weights = (df[col].value_counts() * sample_factor).astype(int)
df.groupby(col).apply(lambda g: g.sample(n=weights[g.name]))
```