# Random selection of a row from a pandas DataFrame with weights

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to randomly select a row from a pandas DataFrame based on provided weights. I tried to use .sample() method with these parameters, but can't get the syntax working:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'label': [1,0,1,-1],
    'ind': [2,3,6,8],
})

df.sample(n=1, weights=[0.5, 0.4, 0.1], axis=0)
```

labels are 1,0 and -1 and I want to assign different weights to each label for random selection.

Comment: To clarify: for this example, you'd want the function to eg. return a row where 'label' is 1 50% of the time?

Comment: Exactly! it supposed to return a row with label 1 50% of the time.

Comment: This seems to be what you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55042334/pandas-sample-with-weights

Comment: I don't want it based on the count in the DataFrame, but pre-defined weights.

Comment: Your weights list is shorter than columns in df. After enlargement it works.

Comment: weights are based on the labels, I have three labels 1,0, and -1 and three weights corresponding to those labels.

Comment: I tried with `weights = {'-1':.5, '0':.4, '1':.1}` but it keeps raising this error `ValueError: weight vector many not include negative value`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should scale the weight so it matches the expected distribution:

```
weights = {-1:0.1, 0:0.4, 1:0.5}

scaled_weights = (pd.Series(weights) / df.label.value_counts(normalize=True))

df.sample(n=1, weights=df.label.map(scaled_weights) )
```

Test distribution with 10000 samples

```
(df.sample(n=10000, replace=True, random_state=1,
           weights=df.label.map(scaled_weights))
   .label.value_counts(normalize=True)
)
```

Output:

```
 1    0.5060
 0    0.3979
-1    0.0961
Name: label, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It was critical to scale weights and I was totally missing that part.

Answer (score 1):

For each row, divide the desired weight by the frequency of that label in the df:

```
weights=df['label'].replace({1:0.5,0:0.4,-1:0.1})/df.groupby('label')['label'].transform('count')

df.sample(n=1, weights=weights, axis=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try following code. It assigns desired weights from dictionary to your rows in df (assuming you gave them in such an order). In case you want weights to be dependent from number of elements - you can replace lambda with more complex function.

```
w = df['label'].apply( lambda x: {-1:0.5, 0:0.4, 1:0.1}[x] )
df.sample(n=1, weights=w, axis=0)
```

Comment: This doesn't do what's asked unfortunately. The weights it passes are [0.5, 0.4, 0.5, 0.1] so it would return an element with label 1 two thirds of the time.

Comment: This wouldn't give the desired distribution `[0.5,0.4,0.1]`.